# How to convert any value to byte array and append it to a byte list?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I want to write a custom binary file for my little game engine.
I worked with C# and I know how to do it in C# with BitConvert or Convert.

But for some reasons I need to do the same in C++.

**Here's my data struct :**

```
Mesh Position    point3(x,y,z)       type: float   size: 4bytes *3 = 12bytes
Mesh Options     point3(b1,b2,b3)    type: bool    size: 1byte  *3 = 3bytes
Mesh Scale       point3(x,y,z)       type: int     size: 4bytes *3 = 12bytes
Mesh Tag         single              type: string  size: 8bytes *1 = 8bytes
```

Now I have an list of unsigned chars :

```
vector<unsigned char> binary_data;
```

And I can use push to add single bytes into it and finally write it with ofstream :

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

vector<unsigned char> binary_data;

binary_data.push_back(0x66);
binary_data.push_back(0xFF); // bool : true
binary_data.push_back(0x00); // bool : false

fout.write((char*)binary_data.data(),binary_data.size());

fout.close();
```

## My Problem

I need to convert my values of any type float,int,bool,uint,double to byte array and append it to my vector list.

And again get them and convert them back to original value.

offsets and byte sizes are all known.

**Here's an example : There's two meshes in scene ..**

- Scale of first : point3(10,5,15)
- Scale of second : point3(25,0,5)

Now I get x y z and convert them to 4 bytes :

```
10 = > 00 00 00 0A
5 = > 00 00 00 05
15 = > 00 00 00 0F
25 = > 00 00 00 19
0 = > 00 00 00 00
5 = > 00 00 00 05
```

And I append them to `binary_data` list.

**How can I convert them to byte array and back ?**

Comment: You can use `(char*)` casts with the addresses. Though I believe you rather should lookup serialization techniques.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I need to learn it to make my own serialization system.

Comment: Your code will be platform-dependent (endianness-dependent, to be precise). You'll need to add another byte stating the type (like, 0 for `int`, 1 for `float`, etc), at the beginning of each sequence of bytes which represent a variable.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm ok with that , it's just for pc and windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::memcpy` like this:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> void serialize(std::vector<char> &v, const T &obj) {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,"Can only serialize trivially copyable objects.");
  
  auto size = v.size();
  v.resize(size + sizeof(T));

  std::memcpy(&v[size], &obj, sizeof(T));
}
```

Deserialization can be done similarly, there is also a choice between copying into an existing object and creating a new one.

```
template <typename T>
void deserialize(const std::vector<char> &v, std::size_t offset, T &obj) {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,"Can only deserialize trivially copyable objects.");
  
  std::memcpy(&obj, &v[offset], sizeof(T));
}
template <typename T>
T deserialize(const std::vector<char> &v, std::size_t offset) {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,"Can only deserialize trivially copyable objects.");

  T obj;  
  deserialize(v,offset,obj);
  return obj;
}
```

You should get familiar with the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) before you do any type-casting.

Note that only `trivially_copyable` types can be serialized with `memcpy` and do not serialize any class with pointers. Of course none of this is compatible across machines, architectures, or compilers unless specific layout in `T` is enforced.

Comment: This means that all values are of the same type.

Comment: No, it does not? OP said they have access to all sizes and offsets.

Comment: How do I call this function in a loop?

Comment: @Quimby thank you and yes all data are fixed and are known size with offset.

Comment: Dear @Quimby your code worked really well and solved my problem , I created my custom binary data and it works just fine. Accepted.

Comment: @LinkinGarden I'm glad to hear that :)